# Upgrade Jam-based targets to native targets in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm running Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion and I have a very old Xcode 1.0 project whose targets are Jam-based. When I'm trying to build such a target, Xcode tells me that "Jam is deprecated and has been removed; targets that use Jam must be upgraded to native targets. For more information on doing this, consult the Xcode documentation.".

Unfortunately, neither could I find anything in Xcode 4's documentation, nor could I locate Xcode 3's "Project > Upgrade To Native Target" menu item anywhere in Xcode 4.

How can I do the target conversion in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lack of answers I conclude that there are only two ways to achieve what I wanted:

- Either set up Xcode 3 for doing the conversion or
- Recreate the project by hand in Xcode 4.